# Unable to compile Ruby with OpenSSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, openssl, ubuntu-12.04

My system contains OpenSSL but Ruby is unable to require it. I was told that I must have installed Ruby before I had openssl in my system and that I have to rebuild ruby. So I went to the Ruby directory and typed.

```
pushd ext/openssl
sudo ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
popd
```

And then I was going to reconfigure Ruby by typing:

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

The problem is that after I run the extconf.rb file which works fine and I type `sudo make`, it gives this error message.

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/include/ruby.h', needed by `ossl_digest.o'.  Stop.
```

I don't know what that means or how to fix it. Please help!

Screenshot:

[image: As you can see that only happens when it enters openssl. It can't read openssl for some reason.]

Comment: I've never had to manually run any `extconf.rb`s in order to compile Ruby with SSL support, and I do not think you're supposed to. I'd try running `make clean`, and then do the regular configure / make / make install dance again. Provided you have a standard OpenSSL present, Ruby should pick it up all by itself.

Comment: make sure you have `libssl-dev` installed

Comment: @janfoeh : Tried that. Same thing happened. Still can't require 'openssl'

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I do have `libssl-dev` installed.

Comment: Just install rubies via [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)

Comment: Struggling with this myself. If you check in `../../include`, you'll see that `ruby.h` exists. Maybe we can change the offending file to use it

Answer (score 13):

Add this to your `Makefile` in `../ext/openssl` (after using `ruby extconf.rb`):

`top_srcdir = ../..`

[image]

You then should be able to use `make` and `make install` without issue

Answer (score 2):

You need libssl-dev if you want to compile Ruby from source.